# How to send a key ASCII value 0?

Tags: c#, winforms, sendkeys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restrict numbers and letters in textbox - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601972/restrict-numbers-and-letters-in-textbox-c-sharp)

I have a textbox called `TextBox1`. The user should only be allowed to enter capital letters. Other characters have to be denied. How can I do that?

```
private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".Contains(Convert.ToChar(e.KeyValue)))
    {
        SendKeys.Send(Convert.ToChar(0).ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restrict numbers and letters in textbox - C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601972/restrict-numbers-and-letters-in-textbox-c-sharp) or [How can I restrict the values a user enters into TextBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142292/how-can-i-restrict-the-values-a-user-enters-into-textbox)

Comment: [Regex](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match) would seem to be a nicer way of doing this

Comment: Is it windows application or web application ?

Comment: Instead of using "ABC..." i would prefer to check the key like
if(e.KeyCode < 65 || e.KeyCode > 90) e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

Comment: I don't think he is asking how to restrict the items entered. He is asking how to send ASCII 0 to `SendKeys()` hence it probably isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [MaskedTextbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx) instead. Much easier. Your mask can be something like this: `>???????????` depending on the maximal allowed length.

Comment: Oh yeah. You've the masktextbox (Smart)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".Contains(Convert.ToChar(e.KeyValue)))
        e.Handled = true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the KeyEventArgs e there is a property called SuppressKeyPress. You can set this to true if the given key is not in your list. Then the key will not be passed to your textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`MaskedTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx). Why do you use SendKeys anyway, and what do you think the 0 character does?

Comment: So you solved that in Delphi. Replace the key value with value the ASCII-code 0.