# How could i make a textbox that accepts only numeric values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I want to make a textbox that allows only numeric values to be entered.
how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

use `RegularExpressionValidator`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Only Numbers allowed" ValidationExpression="\d+"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

[How to allow only integers in a textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732455/how-to-allow-only-integers-in-a-textbox/9732876#9732876)

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET try this:

```
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer" 
 ControlToValidate="TxtBox" ErrorMessage=Error" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ASP.NET Regular Expression Validator and write a RegEx that only accepts numeric values.

If you want to intercept keystrokes, so that only numerical keys are entered, you'll have to use JavaScript (I wouldn't do that).

Answer (score 0):

dear you can do this by jquery try this if you are using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#txtboxToFilter").keydown(function (e) {
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
         // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || 
         // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
             // let it happen, don't do anything
             return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Why JQUERY? OP has not tagged it!

Comment: dear its a suggestion if its good for him then he will tak it as i ask in my answer if you use jquery then use it

Comment: Thank you. I don't have knowledge of Jquery, I'm Just Novice to programming with having prior knowledge of C#, Sql Server. though I Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="VGrpSave" SetFocusOnError="false" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Only numeric values are allowed" ControlToValidate="txtID" ValidationExpression="\d*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" ValidationGroup="VGrpSave" Text="Submit"></asp:Button>
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" DisplayMode="List" ShowMessageBox="True" ShowSummary="false" ValidationGroup="VGrpSave" />
```