# Validation in webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my web form I have 2 field that should only accept number (the calculation result of their value should shown in the third field. The RegularValidation of those two fields works fine before user click submit button. but NOT after. How to handle it?

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" placeholder="Liter"></asp:TextBox><span style="color:red;font-weight:bold"> *</span>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="This is required" ForeColor="Red"  ValidationGroup="test" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" runat="server" ForeColor="red" ErrorMessage="Enter only numbers!" ValidationExpression="\d+" Display ="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The submit button:

```
 protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
           TextBox3.Text = ((Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) * 4.18 * Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text)) / 3600).ToString();
           double result = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox3.Text);
           TextBox3.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", result);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow only integers in a textbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732455/how-to-allow-only-integers-in-a-textbox)

Comment: No...It's completely different than that

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function / method like this to pass the value of the TextBox

```
public static bool isNumeric(string val, System.Globalization.NumberStyles NumberStyle)
{
    Int32 result;
    return Int32.TryParse(val, NumberStyle,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out result);
}
```

Call and check the method for example passing the following

```
var _isNumeric2 = isNumeric("9.", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Integer);
```

> Replace the first paramtere with the TextBox3.Text value

Comment: Thanks @MethodMan, but the TextBox1 and TextBox2 shall be checked!

Comment: then make the check / call appropriate there are several ways to handle this if this works then mark it as the acceptable answer.. you could change the method to work with any text value

Answer (score 0):

All was needed is to add `ValidationGroup="test"` same as the field. The solution is:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" placeholder="Liter"></asp:TextBox><span style="color:red;font-weight:bold"> *</span>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="This is required" ForeColor="Red"  ValidationGroup="test" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" runat="server" ForeColor="red" ErrorMessage="Enter only numbers!" ValidationExpression="\d+" ValidationGroup="test" Display ="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```