# Asp.net C# InputBox only accepts numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net, inputbox

my question is simple, I need to know how to only allow integers to my InputBox in ASP.Net C#, without that tag thing , is there any other way ?

Thank you guys

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732455/how-to-allow-only-integers-in-a-textbox

Comment: Thank you for the help man ! But I already found it :P

Answer (score 0):

The code is :

```
function numericFilter(txb) {
   txb.value = txb.value.replace(/[^\0-9]/ig, "");
}
```

call it in on key up

```
<input type="text" onKeyUp="numericFilter(this);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Only Numbers allowed" ValidationExpression="\d+"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `asp:CompareValidator`. Like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTotal" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CompareValidator ID="compTotal" 
    runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="txtTotal" 
    ErrorMessage="ValueNotNumeric" 
    Type="Integer" Operator="DataTypeCheck"></asp:CompareValidator>
```